# How to solve this integral equation $f(x)=x+2+\int_0^x f(t)\sin (x-t)dt$?

Tags: calculus

Find $f(x)$ when it meets the following:

$$f(x)=x+2+\int_0^x f(t)\sin (x-t)dt$$
$$\\$$
I tried to differentiate both sides but was so confused how to differentiate the integral as it also includes $x$.

Then I converted as

$$\int_0^x f(t)\sin (x-t)dt=\sin x\int_0^x f(t)\cos tdt- \cos x \int_0^x f(t)\sin tdt$$

And

$$f'(x)=1+\int_0^x f(t)\cos (x-t)dt$$

but have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: You can use Laplace tramsform.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea too, as that's the convolution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we can write
$$f(x)=x+2+\sin x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\cos tdt-\cos x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin tdt\tag1$$
we have
$$f'(x)=1+\cos x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\cos tdt+\sin xf(x)\cos x+\sin x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin tdt-\cos xf(x)\sin x$$
$$=1+\cos x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\cos tdt+\sin x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin tdt$$
and
$$f''(x)=-\sin x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\cos tdt+\cos xf(x)\cos x+\cos x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin tdt+\sin xf(x)\sin x$$
$$=f(x)+x+2-f(x)=x+2$$
using $(1)$.

Finally, note that $f(0)=2,f'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

first idea: differentiate f'(x):

you have $f''(x) = (1+\int_0^x f(t)\cos (x-t)dt)' =f(x) -\int_0^x f(t)\sin(x-t)dt$
and replace $f(x)$ by his value, $f(x)=x+2+\int_0^x f(t)\sin (x-t)dt$.

we obtain $f''(x)= x+2$. so the problem is solved by a simple integration.

second idea: use the Laplace transforms.

Comment: You're 2 mins late, but I appreciate too.

Comment: the time to write it...